# Show a polynomial is irreducible in $\Bbb C[x,y]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

If I have a polynomial with more than one variable, for example $\Bbb C[x,y]$ (with $\Bbb C$ the complex numbers), how can Ii see whether it is irreducible or not?
For example, if I have $x^2-y^2-1$, what can I do to know whether it is irreducible or not? In this example I tried to used Eisenstein's theorem in $\Bbb C[x][z]$, but I don't know how to do it.
Thanks!

Comment: In this case, if you can factor it, you can factor it into first degree polynomials. It shouldn't be too difficult to either find such factors or prove that they cannot exist. But in general there aren't very many simple, powerful tools the way Eisenstein works with a single variable over $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: supposes it has a nontrivial factorization -- computing the resultant of your polynomial and the (degree 1) polynomial it purportedly factors with... is a good way to go

Comment: To apply Eisenstein you need to find a prime factor of $y^2+1$ in $\Bbb C[y]$ with multiplicity one. Where did you get stuck on that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, Eisenstein's criterion is a possibility: rewrite the polynomial as
$$X^2-(Y^2+1)\in \mathbf  C[Y][X]. $$
$Y+\imath$ is an irreducible factor of all coefficients, but the leading coefficient, and $(Y+ \imath)^2=Y^2-2\imath Y-1$ does no divide the constant term.

Comment: Sure! Thank you so much

Comment: Please strive not to add more dupe answers to FAQs. You can quickly locate prior dupes via https://approach0.xyz/search/  besides site search, googling, etc.

Comment: @BillDubuque: I wasn't aware of this link. I'll add it to my bookmarks. Thanks!

Comment: @Bernard That's what *search* is for. Being here almost 6 years and answering over 8000 questions surely you must know that we have *many* prior instances of such questions. How could you not?

Comment: I know that, but I had no way to check. Also, some questions *look* like a standard question, but I feel that the O.P. has specific difficulties with the concepts or techniques involved, and I think I can address these specific difficulties.

Comment: I just wanted to explain why her intuition about Eisenstein was quite correct.

Comment: If need be, you can always add a comment after linking to an (abstract) dupe in order to ensure that the OP knows how to apply the dupe link. By adding yet more dupe answers with no novelty you make it more difficult to locate the" best" answers, and make it more difficult to iteratively refine prior answers (in the hope that they will eventually become "proofs from the book" after enough time being critiqued and improved).

Comment: Yes, but I didn't have myself any dupe to link to, and further, I see links to dupes  as useful more for  someone who doesn't  really know how to start.

Comment: DId you even try to search?

Comment: I didn't know your link.

Comment: You would if you had searched. Why do you refuse to search? If you did you would better see how the many hundreds of (rushed) dupe answers *greatly* complicates using the site to locate (the best) answers to questions.